# Access Html.BeginForm declared in MasterPage from child

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I've run into an instance where I'd like to change the Enctype of the form declared in my current view's master page. I'd like to make the change in order to support attachments via Request.Files.

Alternately is it possible to nest form tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to do that. Here's how you can do it with jQuery.

```
$('#masterForm').attr('enctype', 'new value');
```